# when looping through dom elements, when to use "this" and when to use loop variable?

Tags: javascript, dom, this

I'm a javascript/dom noob coming from mainly Python and Clojure, and the semantics of referring to things in the dom are really confusing me.

Take the following extract from some code which I just wrote into a chrome extension to identify a subset of pages matching criteria defined in `testdownloadpage` and then hang eventlisteners on pdf download links to intercept and scrape them.:

```
function hanglisteners() {
    if (testdownloadpage(url)) {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
            var l = links[i];
            if (testpdf(l.href)) {
                l.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    getlink(this.href);
                }, false);
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Originally, I had the call to `getlink` at the bottom reading `getlink(l.href)`, and I thought (evidently naively) that what would happen with that code would be that it would loop through every matching link, and slap a listener on each that called getlink on the url for that link. But that didn't work at all.  I tried replacing `l.href` with `this.href` just as a guess, and it started working.

I'm not sure why `this.href` worked when `l.href` did not.  My best guess is that the javascript interpreter doesn't evaluate `l.href` in an `addEventListener` call until some point later, when `l` has changed to something else(??). But I'm not sure why that should be, or how to know when javascript does evaluate arguments to a function call and when it doesn't...

And now I'm worrying about the higher-up call to `testpdf(l.href)`.  That function is meant to check to make sure a link is a pdf download link before hanging the listener on it.  But is that going to evaluate `l.href` within the loop, and hence correctly evaluate each link?  Or is that also going to evaluate at some point after the loop, and should I be using `this.href` instead?

Can some kind soul please explain the underlying semantics to me, so that I don't have to guess whether referring to the loop variable or referring to `this` is correct?  Thanks!

**EDIT/ADDITION**:

The consensus seems to be that my problem is a (clearly well-known) issue where inner functions in loops are victims of scope leaks s.t. when they're called, unless the inner function closes over *all* the variables it uses, they end up bound to the last element of the loop.  But: why does this code then work?

```js
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
  let a = links[i];
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log(a.href);
  });
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>silly test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <a href="link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="link2">link2</a>
    <a href="link3">link 3</a>
  </p>


</body>
</html>
```

Based on those answers, I'd expect clicking on every link to log "link 3," but they actually log the correct/expected naive results...

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: When a function is used as an event handler, its `this` is set to the element the event fired from (some browsers do not follow this convention for listeners added dynamically with methods other than addEventListener).

Comment: hmm @elclanrs are you saying that the problem doesn't have anything to do with the loop, but something having to do with scope leak to the inner function?

Comment: ... pondering... just to make sure I understand answers at the link above, an alternative solution would be to wrap `addEventListener` in some kind of 2-arity function that then closes over the current value of `l.href` at each iteration of the loop?

Comment: You can find the best answer at [MDN Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). In a nutshell, `var l` changes in the loop and is very different (if exists) at the moment the function is called. Side note: I think about special tag `closures-in-loops`. Is it good idea?

Comment: So here's a follow-up puzzle. This https://gist.github.com/paultopia/31ca18d2230ac8c236bd130e0b6c31cf works as expected, i.e., clicking each link logs the correct `href`, rather than each logging "link 3."  But shouldn't it display the same problem behavior, i.e., `a` is already at the end of the loop when any of the functions are called?

Comment: Read about differences between `var` and `let` [MDN let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for full answer in behavior.

Comment: Oooooooh. I hadn't even noticed the let, copied from earlier answer below.  Thank you?

Comment: (That was supposed to be a "thank you!"  Also, I didn't know JS had a let!  It feels so nice and lispy now!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because the loop variable has already changed by the time the listener actually fires. You should be able to see this with the example below.

```js
function setup(){
  var root = document.getElementById('root');
  var info = document.createElement('div');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    // create a button
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    
    // set up the parameters
    btn.innerHTML = i
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
      info.innerHTML = ('i = ' + i + ', but the button name is ' +  event.target.innerHTML);
    })
    
    // add the button to the dom
    root.appendChild(btn)
  }
  var info = document.createElement('div');
  info.innerHTML = 'The Value of i is ' + i
  root.appendChild(info)
}


// run our setup function
setup();
```

```html
<div id="root">
  
</div>
```

so what you need to do is save off a copy of `l` for later use. `addEventListener` is automatically storing the element in `this` for exactly this reason. Another very good way to do this, however if you don't want to mess with `this` for some reason is to use a generator function (a function that creates a function).

for instance:

```
function clickListener(i, info){
    return function(event){
        info.innerHTML = ('i = ' + i + ', but the button name is ' +  event.target.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

This way we can put the variables `i` and `info` into scope for the listener function which is called later without the values changing.

putting this code into our example above, we get the following snippet

```js
function clickListener(i, info){
    return function(event){
        info.innerHTML = ('i = ' + i + ', but the button name is ' +  event.target.innerHTML);
    }
}

function setup(){
  var root = document.getElementById('root');
  var info = document.createElement('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    // create a button
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    
    // set up the parameters
    btn.innerHTML = i
    // use the generator to get a click handler
    btn.addEventListener('click', clickListener(i, info))
    
    // add the button to the dom
    root.appendChild(btn)
  }
  info.innerHTML = 'The Value of i is ' + i
  root.appendChild(info)
}


// run our setup function
setup();
```

```html
<div id="root">
  
</div>
```

**EDIT: Answering revised question**

In your second iteration of code, you use the `let` keyword introduced with `ES6`. This keyword is specifically designed to give javascript variables more traditional block scope. In our case it makes the variable scoped to the specific iteration of the loop. A similar example can be seen on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Cleaner_code_in_inner_functions). If you can support `ES6` in your application/build system, using let is a great way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the function of event listeners, `this` is bound to the DOM element for which the event listener is for. Imagine the following code:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
  let a = links[i];
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(this === a); // => true
  })
}
```

The two would be identical, so you can use either whenever

Comment: hmm... I just tested this to verify for myself it works, but now extra confused as to why my code in the question would work with `this` but fail with the loop variable... (I suppose I could have just had some other bug!  might have to start digging through commit history to make sure...)

Comment: @PaulGowder, see the question I linked in the comments above, that's the issue: loop + closure.

Comment: @elclanrs I haven't even though of closure. @PaulGowder you should use `this` then